# Wrong date when parsing date string from other time zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I tried to parse this time string "21:58:06 Apr 29, 2015 PDT". What is the right way to do that?

first approach:

```
zone      = Time.zone
Time.zone = "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
payed_at  = Time.parse params[:payment_date]

payed_at.in_time_zone(zone)
```

result:

```
Thu, 30 Apr 2015 10:21:30 CEST +02:00
```

second guess:

```
payed_at      = DateTime.parse date
```

result:

```
Thu, 30 Apr 2015 21:58:29 +0000
```

the correct result would be

```
Thu, 30. April 2015, 06:58 Uhr
```

environment:

```
ruby '2.1.5'
gem 'rails', '~> 3.2.15'
```

Comment: http://jessehouse.com/blog/2013/11/15/working-with-timezones-and-ruby-on-rails/

Comment: thanks for reminding me of that blog post, it's a great source for TimeZone stuff in Rails 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have `rails` specified in tags, here is an `ActiveSupport`ed solution:

```
tz = ActiveSupport::TimeZone['US/Pacific']
tz.parse("21:58:06 Apr 29, 2015 PDT").localtime
#⇒ 2015-05-01 06:58:29 +0200
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse using **strptime** method
Eg : `DateTime.strptime('December 09, 2011', '%B %d, %Y')`

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-_strptime